# Glassfish web service authorization

Tags: java, web-services, security, glassfish

I've set up a web service using JAX-WS deployed to Glassfish 3.1.1. I've managed to set up SSL with client certificates (mutual authentication), but I can't figure out how to do proper authorization. I like to setup roles for read only access, for updating and deleting data.

The Java EE 6 Tutorial and the glassfish security guide state, that one cannot add users to certificate realm [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html). So what is the proper way to authorize users while using mutual authentication? Do I have to use usernames and passwords on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggktf.html#gksdc

```
public class CertificateLM extends AppservCertificateLoginModule
{

    protected void authenticateUser() throws LoginException
    {
        // get the DN from the X500Principal.
        String dname = getX500Principal().getName();

        // retrieve the groups of the DN from an external source, e.g. from LDAP
        String[] groups = getGroupsFromLDAP( dname ); 

        if( groups != null ) {
             commitUserAuthentication( groups );
        }
        else {
             throw new LoginException( "DN is unknown." );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a working approach. I was hoping for a solution which could leverage the role based access control as provided by Java EE and glassfish (using security annotations, user/group administration). That's why I actually did use basic authentication together with client certificates.

Comment: The snipped above is plugged into the JAAS layer of the application server.
Your JEE application will still be able to use standard JEE security, like @annotations.

Comment: I see. Can this be linked to the user account management as well, so that no external system (like the LDAP one from above) is needed?

Comment: By "user account management" do you mean managing user from the GF admin interface? If true, short answer is NO, because that features uses a different realm (fileRealm).

Comment: The long is answer is YES, but you will need to dig into GF sources and read about GF security and custom realms. You should be able to link your cert login module to the FileLoginModule implementation - actually I did it some long time ago.

Comment: But be aware that for a production system with more than let's say 20 users, an external user management system becomes mandatory

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was only asking out of curiosity.